# Finding the maximum and minimum of $f(x) = \frac{x^p +1}{(x^2 +1)^{p/2}}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

I want to find the maximum and minimum of $$f(x) = \frac{x^p +1}{(x^2 +1)^{p/2}}$$ (where $t \in R^+$ and $p\in R$) without using a computer.

I would proceed by setting the derivative equal to zero, but that gives me

$$x^{p-1} (x^2+1)^{p/2} - 2x^{p+1}\frac{p}{2}(x^2 +1)^{(p-2)/2} = 0$$

and I am unsure how to find my critical points.

Comment: Do you mean $x$ instead of $t$?

Comment: It is useful to note that the derivative factors into $f(x)  = p x^{p-1} \left(x^2+1\right)^{-\frac{p}{2}-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply begin by factoring out

$$x^{p} (x^{2}+1)^{p/2}$$

Steps:

$$x^{p} (x^{2}+1)^{p/2}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{xp}{x^{2}+1})=0$$

We can now eliminate $x^{p} (x^{2}+1)^{p/2}$ and note that `0` is a critical point.

$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{xp}{x^{2}+1} = 0$$

can be simplified to

$$x^{2}+1-x^{2}p=0$$

which can be simplified to

$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{p-1}}$$

giving two more critical points.

Comment: Thanks! How would I discover which one is a max and min?

Comment: @Monolite Evaluate the value of the original function at each critical point.